# Prove polynomial has at least $n-1$ distinc real roots

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Let $W(x)$ be a polynomial with $n$ distinct real roots. Prove for any $k \in \mathbb{R}$ polynomial $P(x)=k\cdot W(x) + W'(x)$ has at least $n-1$ distinct real roots.

I know how to show it for $k=0$ then it follow from roll theorem but show it for $k \neq 0$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a hint: Look at $e^{kx}W(x)$.

Comment: ok so consider $Q(x)=e^{kx} \cdot W(x)$ then $Q(x)$ has $n$ distinct real roots. $Q'(x)=e^{kx}(k\cdot W(x)+W'(x))$ and from rolle theorem $Q'(x)$ has at least $n-1$ distinct real roots so have $k\cdot W(x)+W'(x)$ since $e^{kx}$ have no roots. Is it correct ?